# How to attach external fingerprint scanner to flutter attendance application?

Tags: android, flutter, web, biometrics, digital-persona-sdk

I am creating an attendance application using flutter. The owner requires that the attendance should use biometrics. The device may be implemented with android or web. The device provided is Digital Persona U.are.U 4500. I am unable to find any helping material for this. Please help me.

I have tried to read the data from fingerprint reader using usb_serial package and use_device package. The usb_device package shows no output and doesn't even want to connect. The usb_serial connects to the fingerprint scanner, asks for permission to use it and shows its name and productId in attached devices list, but I am not able to get input from reader using this library.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I have found solution to read from fingerprint scanner attached through usb port. https://github.com/shodgson/uareu. This project is exactly that.

Comment: @nativeprogrammers What if we're using another device other than Digital Persona U.are.U 4500, will it still work?

Comment: @nativeprogrammers Could you find the solution to connect the Persona U with the Flutter app?

Answer (score 0):

Windows > IdentaMaster > Digital Persona U.are.U 4500

https://identamaster.com/

Answer (score -1):

If you use ZKTeco products, i've developed plugin based on Native Anroid SDK:

https://pub.dev/packages/zkfinger10

Comment: OP has already mentioned the device used (Digital Persona U.are.U 4500)

Comment: Do you have the same for Kotlin or Java?

Comment: @RajatGupta Answer can be useful for others too, not only for questionnaire